# How do I automatically click this button?

Tags: javascript, button, click

How I can make a script that automatically clicks this button?

```
<div data-v-2aabe0a6="" class="box-inner">
  <span data-v-2aabe0a6="">JOIN</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an actual `<button>`?

Answer (score 0):

this code, if inserted where necessary, will work

```
document.querySelector('div[data-v-2aabe0a6=""]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rethink your CSS. Have a new meaningful class name like "join" which describes the button, and use that alongside "box-inner". Then target "join".

(Sidenote: maybe change that markup to something more semantically meaningful too by using `<button>`.)

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.join');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  console.log('Joined!');
}

button.click();
```

```css
.join { padding: 1em 2em; background-color: lightgreen; }
.join:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.box-inner { box-shadow: 5px 10px 5px pink inset; }
```

```html
<button data-v-2aabe0a6="" class="join box-inner">
  JOIN
</button>
```